# Non-Metahumans with Adept powers

Tags: lore, shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

In Shadowrun lore, as well as in Running Wild, Street Grimoire, and other places, spirits, dragons, and other things can have the abilities of a mage (though spirits can't conjure most of the time).

Is there any lore reason why a spirit, dragon, etc would not be able to be an adept gaining adept powers?

Comment: Note: Running Wild is a 2009 sourcebook for SR4.

Comment: I am aware. But Shadowrun tends to retain fluff from previous editions unless it's been contradicted, and I am looking for any lore supporting or negating the option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drakes, Free Spirits, and Shapeshifters are inherently magic. They get a magic attribute just to be what they are and stop being that if the Magic attribute ever falls to 0. And nothing in the rules forbids the more physical of them from getting the magic-wielder abilities Adept, Mystic Adept, or Magician. Spirits are a little different: they are all Magicians and may not possess the spirit-interaction skills of summoning/binding/banishing. But for the rest, they may gain the two adept types and gain adept powers as they see fit.

### Drakes and Shapeshifters

While not every of these is an Adept or Magician in lore, many are. All Drakes and Shapeshifters had a dual nature in 3rd and 4th editions (no longer forced upon one in the 5th) and with that could learn assessing.

Some examples of the few Shadowtalkers or very prominent characters who belong are at least Adepts:

- Drake is a Drake and Adept. He elaborated on his journey in *Dragons of the 6th World*
- Saif Alhazred is a Drake and Magician (*Datapuls ADL*)
- Branwen is a Drake and Magician (*Dragons of the 6th World*/*Survival of the Fittest*)
- Ryan Mercury, leader of the Draco Foundation, is a Drake and Adept (*Threats, Threats 2, Loose Alliances, Dragons of the 6th World, Street Legends*)
- Monika Stüeler-Waffenschmidt, CEO of the Frankfurter Bankenverein, is an Elf, Drake and Magician (*Schockwellen, Corporate Enclaves (german)*)
- Kitsune was a Fox-shapeshifter and Adept (*Corporate Enclaves, Attitude, the SNES games*)
- Robert Paulsen is a Seal-shapeshifter and Magician following an eco-shaman path (*Megakons 2078*)

On the other hand, not all shapeshifters and drakes are such adept at wielding magic, or their status is unknown:

- Romulus is just a Wolf-shapeshifter and Dual-natured, but explicitly not an Adept (*The Forever Drug*)
- MacDougal was, up to the point he turned into a Drake during *Year of the Comet*, a totally mundane man. It is however unknown if he trained later as the name was never reused.
- Azadeh is known to be a Drake and the partner of Ryan Mercury - but it is unknown if or what kind of magic she wields (*Street Legends*)

### Free Spirits

These are different. **All** Free Spirits are always (considered to be) Magicians (and don't pay for that!), and **none** is an Adept or Mystic Adept (emphasis mine):

> Every free spirit gains the Banishing Resistance power
> (p. 194) **and is considered a full Magician** (p. 69, SR5)
> with the exception that they may never have skills in
> the Conjuring group and may not astrally project from
> an inhabited vessel unless it has the Astral Projection
> power (p. 204). <sup>1</sup>

This rule was there since 3rd edition, and in no edition was any Free Spirit given with any Adept powers. Instead, they would get Spirit powers, which arguably are better than most Adept powers, even if some are functionally identical. It doesn't make them Adepts though.

1 - *Street Grimoire* (2014) p. 203

Answer (score 2):

### No.

There is no explicit lore reason as to why a spirit or dragon could not gain adept powers (or some other form of metacritter or awakened critter).

**Shadowrun is a confusing mishmash of contradictory fluff, though.**  It was written by different authors with different ideas of what *Shadowrun* entails, and to some degree embraced these fluff discrepancies with 'everything is misinformation or just someone's point of view, man' writeups.

Ultimately it is up to the GM of any specific shadowrun game as to what is possible or impossible in their version of shadowrun, as trying to find definitive answers on these kinds of questions turns up 5 answers, all of them complicated and buried deep, and none of them agreeing with any of the others.

Comment: There is one for Spirits: they are automatically magicans

Comment: that is only true if mystic adepts don't exist

Comment: no, you can't have mythic adept if you already count as magican: you can only have Adept, Mythic Adept or Magician; Spirit is automatically counted as Magician => can't take any of those other merits.

Comment: This question is about lore, not the RAW of character creation.  Also, it's _mystic_ adept, at least, in english.  Mythic <whatever> is a pathfinder term.

Comment: There is **not a single** Free Spirit with adept powers in Shadowrun lore.

Comment: @Trish there is.  many.  Many many many mythological spirits and spirits of man in shadowrun LORE use abilities functionally identical to killing hands, wall running, etc etc, adept stuff.  There are no STATBLOCKS with spirits with adept powers (although some have custom powers _identical_ to adept powers).  Please, if english is not your first language, consider googling specialist terms that you are using.  Mechanics, lore, statblocks, and descriptions are NOT THE SAME THINGS.

Comment: Those are Spirit powers that are functionally identical. It doesn't make them Adepts, they get spirit powers only.